# Camel jms route to IBM MQ immediately shuts down after successful test connection

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-camel, camel-jms

I have used Camel a few times now but this problem is over my head and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. It is a new application that should fetch messages from IBM MQ and place files to disk. The route is very simple:

```
String fromString = "message-queue:XXX.FUNDORDER.YYY.OUT?testConnectionOnStartup=true";

    from(fromString)
        .autoStartup(true)
        .routeId("RouteReceiver")
        .log("Processing message ${exchangeId}")
        .to("file:/in?fileName=${exchangeId}.txt");
```

Here's the code used when creating the Connection factory:

```
public JmsConnectionFactory websphereConnectionFactory() throws JMSException
          {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Config.class);

    logger.info("ibmMqChannel = " + ibmMqChannel);
    logger.info("ibmMqHost = " + ibmMqHost);
    logger.info("ibmMqPort = " + ibmMqPort);
    logger.info("ibmMqQueueManagerName = " + ibmMqQueueManagerName);


    /*
     * Create MQConnectionFactory
     */
    final MQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setHostName(ibmMqHost);
    connectionFactory.setPort(ibmMqPort);
    connectionFactory.setChannel(ibmMqChannel);
    connectionFactory.setQueueManager(ibmMqQueueManagerName);
    connectionFactory.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);

    logger.debug("connectionFactory=" + connectionFactory.toString());

    /*
     * Add ConnectionFactory to JmsConfiguration
     */
    final JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();
    jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    /*
     * Add JmsConfiguration to JmsComponent
     */
    final JmsComponent jmsComponent = new JmsComponent();
    jmsComponent.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);
    jmsComponent.setAcknowledgementModeName("AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE");

    /*
     * Add JmsComponent to camelContext
     */
    camelContext.addComponent("message-queue", jmsComponent);


    return connectionFactory;

}
```

Right after the application is started and connection is tested it immediately starts shutting down. No exceptions are thrown. 
When testing locally I'm using a different profile and connects to an ActiveMQ server instead. This runs fine and does what it is supposed to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

/Katarina

Here's an extract of the log right before the route is shut down:

```
2018-01-23 12:13:05:501 o.a.camel.component.jms.JmsConsumer DEBUG - Successfully tested JMS Connection on startup for destination: MY.QUEUE.NAME
2018-01-23 12:13:05:501 o.a.camel.component.jms.JmsConsumer TRACE - Starting listener container org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer@7b02881e on destination MY.QUEUE.NAME
2018-01-23 12:13:05:532 o.a.c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer DEBUG - Established shared JMS Connection
2018-01-23 12:13:05:532 o.a.c.u.c.CamelThreadFactory TRACE - Created thread[Camel (Client Robur messaging service) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[MY.QUEUE.NAME]] -> Thread[Camel (Client Robur messaging service) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[MY.QUEUE.NAME],5,main]
2018-01-23 12:13:05:547 o.a.c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer DEBUG - Resumed paused task: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker@503d687a
2018-01-23 12:13:05:547 o.a.camel.component.jms.JmsConsumer DEBUG - Started listener container org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer@7b02881e on destination MY.QUEUE.NAME
2018-01-23 12:13:05:547 o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext INFO  - Route: RouteReceiver started and consuming from: message-queue://MY.QUEUE.NAME?errorHandlerLoggingLevel=TRACE&jmsMessageType=Text&testConnectionOnStartup=true
2018-01-23 12:13:05:547 o.a.camel.support.ServiceSupport TRACE - Starting service
2018-01-23 12:13:05:547 o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext INFO  - Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
2018-01-23 12:13:05:547 o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext INFO  - Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: Client Robur messaging service) started in 5.974 seconds
2018-01-23 12:13:05:547 o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext DEBUG - start() took 5974 millis
2018-01-23 12:13:05:563 o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext DEBUG - onApplicationEvent: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent[source=org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication@53976f5c]
2018-01-23 12:13:05:563 se.tradechannel.IbmMqApplication INFO  - Started IbmMqApplication in 37.347 seconds (JVM running for 39.742)
2018-01-23 12:13:05:563 se.tradechannel.IbmMqApplication INFO  - Message Queue application started.
2018-01-23 12:13:05:563 o.a.c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer TRACE - runningAllowed() -> true
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext DEBUG - onApplicationEvent: org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent[source=org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@621be5d1: startup date [Tue Jan 23 12:12:29 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy]
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext INFO  - Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: Client Robur messaging service) is shutting down
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper TRACE - Stopping service org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteController@35e2d654
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper TRACE - Shutting down service org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteController@35e2d654
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 o.a.camel.support.ServiceSupport TRACE - Service already stopped
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy INFO  - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 o.a.c.m.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy TRACE - Checking whether to register org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.RejectableThreadPoolExecutor@279ccd56[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0][ShutdownTask] from route: null
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 o.a.c.i.DefaultExecutorServiceManager DEBUG - Created new ThreadPool for source: org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy@1e800aaa with name: ShutdownTask. -> org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.RejectableThreadPoolExecutor@279ccd56[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0][ShutdownTask]
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 o.a.c.u.c.CamelThreadFactory TRACE - Created thread[Camel (Client Robur messaging service) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] -> Thread[Camel (Client Robur messaging service) thread #2 - ShutdownTask,5,main]
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy DEBUG - There are 1 routes to shutdown
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy TRACE - Shutting down route: RouteReceiver with options [Default,CompleteCurrentTaskOnly]
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 o.a.c.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy TRACE - Suspending: Consumer[message-queue://MY.QUEUE.NAME?errorHandlerLoggingLevel=TRACE&jmsMessageType=Text&testConnectionOnStartup=true]
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper TRACE - Suspending service Consumer[message-queue://MY.QUEUE.NAME?errorHandlerLoggingLevel=TRACE&jmsMessageType=Text&testConnectionOnStartup=true]
2018-01-23 12:13:05:766 o.a.c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer DEBUG - Stopping listenerContainer: org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer@7b02881e with cacheLevel: 3 and sharedConnectionEnabled: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using SpringBoot? If yes, is it possible that your application does not block and therefore simply shuts down after startup because the main method is done?

According to http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html there are many ways to block the main thread in a SpringBoot application (see Link for further details):

- Your route class extends the `org.apache.camel.spring.boot.FatJarRouter` class
- Use `CamelSpringBootApplicationController.blockMainThread()`
- include the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in pom.xml
- Set the property `camel.springboot.main-run-controller` to `true` in property or YAML file

Comment: Thanks for answer. Would adding the line: "camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true" to properties file achieve same effect as "applicationController.blockMainThread()"?

Comment: Yes. And there are even more options to do it, I just updated my answer.

Comment: Didn't have opportunity to test until now and the property camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true helped. The application doesnt shut down and now I finally managed to read messages. Thank you!